# convert a string to JSON object array- NOdejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, arrays, json

Lets presume I am sending a POST request to /api/products. My body is like below

```
{
      "products":[
                {
                    "id":"5f5065e44a12bd00232bcc6g",
                    "status":"true"
                },
                {
                    "id":"5f5065e44a12bd00232bcc6g",
                    "status":"true"
                }
     ]
}
```

In my route I am trying to convert the above products to a JSON Object;

Below is my server code

```
const { products } = req.body;
console.log(JSON.parse(products));
```

but this gives me the error  "message": "Something went wrong Unexpected token o in JSON at position 1"

How can i achieve this??

Cheers

Screenshots added

[image]

[image]

Tried below as well. But no luck

Nothing works.

```
const products = req.body;
console.dir(typeof products); // 'object'
console.dir(products); // { products: '[object Object]' } 

const { products } = req.body;
console.dir(typeof products); // 'string'
console.dir(products); // '[object Object]'
```

postman developer console is as below. Doesnt seem to be an issue

```
{
    "products":[
            {
                "id":"5f5065e44a12bd00232bcc6g",
                "status":"true"
            },
            {
                "id":"5f5065e44a12bd00232bcc6g",
                "status":"true"
            }
    ]
}
```

Comment: If that's your body, it's not valid JSON--you can't have a property key outside an object. (*Is* that the body?)

Comment: *"In my route I am trying to convert the above products to a JSON Object;"* JSON is a *textual notation* for data exchange. [(More here.)](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2904181/157247) If you're dealing with JavaScript source code, and not dealing with a *string*, you're not dealing with JSON. It sounds like you're trying to convert a string containing JSON to an object (not a *JSON* object, just an object).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not a JSON object, JSON objects are surrounded by curly braces.

if you return
`{"products": [ { "id":"5f5065e44a12bd00232bcc6g", "status":"true" }, { "id":"5f5065e44a12bd00232bcc6g", "status":"true" } ]}`

then it will be worked.

Answer (score 1):

Look at the content of your variable `products`, and your debugger.

In this line you're using an object destructuring assignment but the right hand side isn't an object, it's a string:

```
const { products } = req.body;
```

Try this instead:

```
const { products } = JSON.parse(req.body);
```

**EDIT** you appear to be using Express middleware or similar.   There's a good chance that your object has already been converted from JSON so you just need your original line and *not* the `JSON.parse` line.

```
const { products } = req.body;
console.dir(products);
```

Comment: This seems much more on the right track, with the caveat that it's not 100% clear what's actually in the body.

Comment: @DaveNewton yup - that body really should have `{ .. }` around it,

Comment: I have added json middleware from body-parser

Comment: @ShankaSomasiri right, so you shouldn't need to also `JSON.parse` the body yourself!

Answer (score 1):

The best thing to do would be to fix what you're sending to `/api/products` by putting `{}` around it, like this:

```
{
    "products":[
            {
                "id":"5f5065e44a12bd00232bcc6g",
                "status":"true"
            },
            {
                "id":"5f5065e44a12bd00232bcc6g",
                "status":"true"
            }
    ]
}
```

Now it's valid JSON, and you can convert it via `JSON.parse`:

```
const obj = JSON.parse(req.body);
console.log(obj);
const { products } = obj;
```

or just

```
const { products } = JSON.parse(req.body);
```

Notice I'm using the entire body there. That will give you an object with a property (`products`) with the array of products. Alternatively, instead of parsing it manually, you could use middleware that would parse it automatically so that `req.body` is the parsed result, in which case it's just:

```
console.log(req.body);
const { products } = req.body;
```

---

If for some reason you can't send correct JSON, but it will always be in the form you've shown, you could add the `{}` afterward like this:

```
const obj = JSON.parse("{" + req.body + "}");
console.log(obj);
const { products } = obj;
```

or just

```
const { products } = JSON.parse("{" + req.body + "}");
```

**but I strongly recommend not doing that**, not least because you can't use middleware and sending malformed data around tends not to be ideal. Instead, send valid JSON in the first place.

Comment: I tried all your suggestions. But none of them work. i did console.log of my req.body and it shows below { product: '[object Object]' }. I am still wondering why this is not working

Comment: From that it sounds like the client-side code isn't sending what you've put in your question. Specifically, it sounds like the client-side code is manually creating a JSON string (**never** a good idea) and using string concatenation (`+`) with an object. When you do that, the object gets converted to `"[object Object]"` and added to the string.

Comment: In that case what is the best way as you think T.J? I have added some screenshots as well

Comment: Is it possible that some middleware is already converting the body from JSON?   Using `console.dir` instead of `console.log` would reveal that.

Comment: @Alnitak - Indeed. As would a debugger.

Comment: I have added json middleware from body-parser.

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out.

Thanks to @T.j and @Alnitak was able to get this sorted. Used

```
let obj = req.body;
```

But i had an issue with my validator.

```
body('products')
      .trim()
      .not()
      .isEmpty()
      .withMessage('Custom product must have a main product'),
```

In the above code using .trim() converted the products into a string and once I removed the trim() it works perectly. Thanks all for the thoughts

Answer (score -2):

Try with JSON.stringify()

Otherwise, maybe you were declaring an object (const { products }), try without the {}

Comment: OP claims they *have* a string, stringifying it would be... redundant.